# Service class has a public property that is not resolving

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-bsd, funq

I'm having a little trouble understanding why my Manager class is null within the context of the request handling through this example POST method in the Service class.
I registered the Manager and it's dependencies like this example and it seems to be registering fine.
Only way I can get this to work is if I tell the property to go and resolveNamed through the container in the apphost reference.
Thanks!

```
public static class TemplateContainer
{
  public const string DomainName = "Template";

  public static Funq.Container Configure(Funq.Container container)
  {

        container.Register<IUOWMongo<TemplateMongoContext>>(DomainName, c =>
             new UOWMongo<TemplateMongoContext>(
                  c.ResolveNamed<string>(Constants.NamedString)
                  )
             ).ReusedWithin(Funq.ReuseScope.Request);

        container.Register<IMongoTemplateRepository>(DomainName, c =>
             new MongoTemplateRepository<TemplateMongoContext>(
                        c.ResolveNamed<IUOWMongo<TemplateMongoContext>>(DomainName)
                  )
             ).ReusedWithin(Funq.ReuseScope.Request);

        container.Register<ITemplateDataManager>(DomainName, c =>
             new TemplateDataManager(c.ResolveNamed<IMongoTemplateRepository>(DomainName))
             ).ReusedWithin(Funq.ReuseScope.Default);

        return container;
  }
}

public class TemplateService : ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Service
{
  public ITemplateDataManager Manager { get; set; }

  public GetTemplateResponse Post(GetTemplateRequest request)
  {
        var response = new GetTemplateResponse();
        **// Manager is null here!!!
        // Only way I can get it to work is if I do this:
        Manager = AppHostBase.Instance.Container.ResolveNamed<ITemplateDataManager>("Template");**

        return response;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AutoWiring in Funq doesn't look at named dependencies. You can change it to register as a normal dependency:

```
container.Register<ITemplateDataManager>(c =>
     new TemplateDataManager(c.ResolveNamed<IMongoTemplateRepository>(DomainName))
 );
```